# Nature of Dengue Fever Genetic Material

Tags: genetics, dna

Once the genetic material for Dengue Fever is inserted into the human DNA, would the Dengue Fever molecular material be in the form of its own isolated DNA fragment or will it be inserted directly into some existing piece of our DNA?

Comment: I'm looking at the life cycle for dengue virus, it looks like a positive-sense ssRNA virus. The viral genetic material doesn't integrate into the host genome. Someone correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @Kendall you are correct. ss(+)RNA viral genomes behave like mRNA in the host, and are directly translated by ribosomes. The viral proteins thus produced then direct production of more genomes and the assembly of virus particles to infect more cells and other hosts. Viruses that integrate into the host's genome are called *retroviruses*.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification. If you wouldn't mind posting that as an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a 2011 Nature review they provide a figure for the life cycle of the Dengue virus,

[image]

Source: [Immunity to dengue virus: a tale of original antigenic sin and tropical cytokine storms](http://www.nature.com/nri/journal/v11/n8/full/nri3014.html)

The Dengue virus is a positive-sense ssRNA virus. This means the ssRNA that enters the host may immediately be translated. The viral ssRNA does not integrate with the host genome!